# How to make and download pdf-file in Dash app in memory

Tags: plotly-dash, pdfkit

I have a dash app where I want the user to be able to download a pdf-report.

I am able to make it work locally with pdfkit and jinja based on [this method](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1IYtkkEOuoU), but to make it work I have to save the file on the server, then fetch it for download. My users might not want this, so I want  to save the temporary file only in memory (client side).

This is my code:

```
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output
import pdfkit
import jinja2


# Set up sample pdf with pdfkit and jinja based on this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1IYtkkEOuoU

my_name = "Frank "
item1 = "TV"
today_date = "2022"

context = {'my_name': my_name,
           'item1': item1,
           'today_date': today_date}

template_loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader('./')
template_env = jinja2.Environment(loader=template_loader)

html_template = 'my-basic-template.html'
template = template_env.get_template(html_template)
output = template.render(context)

# downloaded wkhtmltopdf locally:
path_wkhtmltopdf = r'C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe'
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=path_wkhtmltopdf)
output_pdf = 'pdf_generated.pdf'
pdfkit.from_string(output, output_pdf, configuration=config)


# Make Dash app
app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Button("Download pdf", id="btn-download-pdf"),
    dcc.Download(id="download-pdf")
])


@app.callback(
    Output("download-pdf", "data"),
    Input("btn-download-pdf", "n_clicks"),
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def func(n_clicks):
    pdf = pdfkit.from_string(output, configuration=config)
    print(output)
    return dcc.send_file("pdf_generated.pdf", "test_pdf.pdf")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Is there a better way to do this?